# Multiprocessing BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closed when using .send() method

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am currently working on a program that uses an online OCR API. This API takes 2-5 seconds to send me a processed image, so instead of making the user wait for all images to be processed, the user can start working on the first image while the rest are processed on a different instance of python using multiprocessing. I have been using `multiprocessing.Pipe()` to send values back and forth. The code is here:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
# importing cv2, PIL, os, json, other stuff

def image_processor():
    # processes the first image in the list, then moves the remaining images to a different python instance:
    p_conn, c_conn = mp.Pipe()
    p = mp.Process(target=Processing.worker, args=([c_conn, images, path], 5))
    p.start()
    
    while True:
        out = p_conn.recv()
        if not out:
            break
        else:
            im_data.append(out)
            p_conn.send(True)


class Processing:
    def worker(data, mode, headers=0):
        # (some if statements go here)
        elif mode == 5:
            print(data[0])
            for im_name in data[1]:
            if data[1].index(im_name) != 0:
                im_path = f'{data[2]}\{im_name}'  # find image path
                im = pil_img.open(im_path).convert('L')  # open and grayscale image with PIL
                os.rename(im_path, f'{data[2]}\Archive\{im_name}')  # move original to archive
                im_grayscale = f'{data[2]}\g_{im_name}'  # create grayscale image path
                im.save(im_grayscale)  # save grayscale image
                    
                ocr_data = json.loads(bl.Visual.OCR.ocr_space_file(im_grayscale)).get('ParsedResults')[0].get('ParsedText').splitlines()
                print(ocr_data)
                data[0].send([im_name, f'{data[2]}\Archive\{im_name}', ocr_data])
                data[0].recv()
            
            data[0].send(False)
```

This leaves me with the following traceback:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BruhK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\BruhK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\BruhK\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\FleetFeet-OCR-Final.py", line 275, in worker
    data[0].send([{im_name}, f'{data[2]}\Archive\{im_name}', ocr_data])
  File "C:\Users\BruhK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 211, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Users\BruhK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 285, in _send_bytes
    ov, err = _winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closed
```

Note that the data sent from the child function to the parent was a 2d or 3d array. In testing I've been able to send 2d and 3d arrays back and forth between child and parent functions.

An example of the code I used for testing is as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import time


def hang(p):
  hang_time = random.randint(1, 5)
  time.sleep(hang_time)
  print(p)
  p.send(hang_time)
  time.sleep(1)


class Child:
  def process():
    start = time.time()
    p_conn, c_conn = mp.Pipe()
    p = mp.Process(target=hang, args=(c_conn,))
    p.start()
    out = p_conn.recv()
    print(f'Waited for {time.time() - start}')
    p.join()
    print(f'New time: {time.time() - start}')
    return out


class Parent:
  def run():
    # do some stuff
    
    print(f'Hang time: {Child.process()}')
    
    # do some stuff


if __name__ == '__main__':
  Parent.run()
```

How do I fix this issue? Is there any additional information needed?

Comment: I'm honestly didn't go trough your entiry code. But based on your problem you described, i would recommend using two [queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) instead of pipes. One queue is to give "jobs" to the ocr-process, the  other one is to send the results back to the user-process. I think that would be a cleaner solution, would that help?

Comment: ..I'm also wondering why you use classes?

Comment: Aaaand it looks you have wrong intenting: Like `for` is not inside the `elif`, and more important the `data[0].send(False)` is inside the `for` loop, so the it sends the `False` after processing the first image and your main process exits the `while(True)`

Comment: @tturbo The indentation was correct in the file on my computer, just put it into stack exchange wrong. As for the `data[0].send(False)` being inside the `for` loop, you'd be correct. I've moved it out of the for loop and, while it has changed the result, I still need to do some testing, as the executor is now getting stuck somewhere, which no new OCR requests being processed. This I should be able to figure out, I will open a new thread if this is not the case. I use classes to organize things so I can understand them better, there are more functions in the main program within the `Processing`

Comment: @tturbo (cont) class. I've struggles to understand the queue system, along with the difference between queues and pipes. I'm still relatively new to multiprocessing, and don't understand it very well. I'll look into using classes. It should be noted though, that moving `data[0].send(False)` out of the `for` loop has stopped the initial error entirely. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad i could help. You may then accept my answer below so the question is closed. Regarding understanding pipes and queues, try find a good side that explains it well to you. However, there is time needed to understand it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks you have wrong indenting: The data[0].send(False) is inside the for loop, so the it sends the False after processing the first image and your main process exits the while(True)

Answer (score 1):

As @tturbo pointed out, the code `data[0].send(False)` was within the `for` loop that it was supposed to be outside of, and this stopped the broken pipe error. I'm not sure why that fixed it, if anyone else would be willing to shed some light on it be my guest. For me, what matters is that it worked. Thank you.